# <dlfcn.> fatal error in C code regarding malloc/free

Tags: c, malloc, free

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stddef.h>

static int counter = 0;

void* malloc(size_t size) {
    void*(*mymalloc)(size_t) = (void* (*)(size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    counter++;
}

void free(void* ptr) {
    printf(ptr);
    counter--;
}

int main(void) {
    int* x = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    *x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", *x);
    free(x);
    printf(counter);
```

When I go to compile the program I get an error such as:
mallocfree.c:2:10: fatal error: dlfcn.h: No such file or directory
I am using Visual Studio Code and was wondering if anyone could help me with the problem. Thanks!

Comment: *I am using Visual Studio Code* -- What compiler are you using?  Visual Studio Code is an IDE, not a compiler.  Also, what language are you using?  C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think it is just C. I am trying to compile it through the terminal (gcc mallocfree.c -ldl)

Comment: I don't know how much luck you will have using `dlfcn.h`  on Windows. Assuming you are compiling on Windows. The fact that the compiler cannot find `dlfcn.h` suggests that it's not going to work.

Comment: Also, there's no point looking up a function and then not using it anywhere. And trying to override malloc in that way seems a bit fraught to me, since it is likely (or at least possible) that dlsym calls malloc.

Comment: Looks like this is linux specific header file for posix functionalities. Can you try. (https://github.com/dlfcn-win32/dlfcn-win32) this on windows?